# CLR SqlUserDefinedAggregate concat on distinct values run multiple times

Tags: c#, sql, .net, clr, aggregate-functions

I am running a CLR c# for concatenating values taken from similar examples online and on books defined here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/aKOC5Q
And I call it with

```
 SELECT unit,dbo.concat(COUNTRY,',') FROM dbo.COUNTRIES GROUP BY unit
```

In the C# code you can see that I am using Distinct() because I do not want duplicates.
The problem here is that apparently this CLR is called multiple times, therefore I get duplicated results as per example:

```
 PalestinePalestine,IsraelPalestine,Israel,Spain
```

According to the c# logic, this should not happen, but as you can see the missing coma between the values makes me understand that the CLR is called multiple times (in addition to the MERGE), therefore I get duplicated results.

Interesting enough, if at line 40 of the c# fiddle I write:

```
AccumulatorList.Add("test");
```

I get, correctly, a single result "test".

Do you have any idea why this problem occurs, and how can I get rid of it and get distinct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was right about sniffing a concurrency problem and running the same query with the MAXDOP 1 option

```
 SELECT unit,dbo.concat(COUNTRY,',') FROM dbo.COUNTRIES GROUP BY unit OPTION(MAXDOP 1)
```

fixes the problem